# PerformancePoint Dashboard Designer Error when creating a Filter - No Filter Data Retrieved

Tags: sharepoint, filter, ssas, performancepoint, dashboard-designer

I'm attempting to create a filter using PerformancePoint's Dashboard Designer. After going through the wizard, however, the "Confirmation" page displays the following message:

> No filter data retrieved
>
> Warning 1: Filter was created but no
>   data was retrieved. To resolve the
>   problme, follow the step(s) below.
>   1. Verify that the data source for this filter is configured properly.
>   2. Check the server event log. Additional information about this
>   problem may have been recorded.

The data source is fine... I used the data source to build the report that the filter is supposed to be filtering... no problems with the report.

As for the logs, the only troubling spot is when the call is made from the PerformancePoint server (part of the SharePoint group) to the SQL Server -- the Event Viewer on the PerformancePoint server has a long message of which the important part is "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Has anyone else had trouble with Filters in PerformancePoint?

Answer (score 2):

This was caused by a limitations in the checksum mechanism for Kerberos which would kill MDX queries. Microsoft released a hotfix for this issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969083